# Passing the '+' character in a POST request in Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to do some automation in a Python script and I have run into a problem.  I am trying to do a POST to a server.

```
url = 'http://www.example.com'
params = {'arg0': 'value', 'arg1': '+value'}

f = urllib.urlopen(url, urllib.urlencode(params))
print f.read()
```

I have done a wireshark capture of the equivalent browser operation, where the second arg, `arg1` is passed as `+value`, however when I do it with Python the `+` gets changed to `%2B`, i.e.

```
Line-based text data: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
arg0=value&arg1=%2Bvalue
```

when it should be:

```
Line-based text data: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
arg0=value&arg1=+value
```

I have also used the Requests module and it seems to do the same thing.

```
url = 'http://www.example.com'
params = {'arg0': 'value', 'arg1': '+value'}

f = requests.post(url, params)
```

Google is not your friend when you have a problem related to '+' as it seems to be a catch all for so much else.

Comment: what version of requests are you using?

Comment: I did a pip install today requests - 0.14.0

Comment: "Google is not your friend when you have a problem related to '+'" - For searching special characters, there are special search engines like http://symbolhound.com/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `+` character is the proper encoding for a space when quoting GET or POST data. Thus, a literal `+` character needs to be escaped as well, lest it be decoded to a space on the other end. See RFC 2396, [section 2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-2.2), [section 3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-3.4) and the [HTML specification, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` section](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1):

> Control names and values are escaped. Space characters are replaced by `+', and then reserved characters are escaped as described in [[RFC1738]](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/references.html#ref-RFC1738), section 2.2.

If you are posting data to an application that does not decode a `+` character to a space but instead treats such data as literal plus signs instead, you need to encode your parameters yourself using the [`urllib.quote` function](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote) instead, specifying that the `+` character is not to be encoded:

```
import urllib
def urlencode_withoutplus(query):
    if hasattr(query, 'items'):
        query = query.items()
    l = []
    for k, v in query:
        k = urllib.quote(str(k), safe=' /+')
        v = urllib.quote(str(v), safe=' /+')
        l.append(k + '=' + v)
    return '&'.join(l)
```

Demo:

```
>>> urlencode_withoutplus({'arg0': 'value', 'arg1': '+value'})
'arg0=value&arg1=+value'
```

When using `requests`, you can simply pass in the result of the above function as the `data` value, but in that case you need to manually set the content type:

```
requests.post(url, urlencode_withoutplus(query),
    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
```

Comment: That seems to be going the opposite way I wanted. Are you saying I should be doing a urllib.quote(params['arg1']) before I do a urllib.urlencode?, because that only yields '%252Bvalue' when I capture on wireshark.

Comment: @DouglasKastle: No, you use this *instead* of urllib.urlencode.

Comment: Sorry I saw your answer before it was completed

Comment: @DouglasKastle: Yeah, I tend to shoot from the hip sometimes; updated as I tested my code properly.

Comment: OK that works in urllib land, thank you, I'm still curious if there is a example for requests.  If I don't get any I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: @DouglasKastle: there you go; `requests` automatically sets the Content-Type for you when posting with `data` set to a sequence or dict of parameters, but won't make that call if `data` is a string. Setting the `Content-Type` header explicitly resolves that.

Answer (score 5):

```
urllib2.quote(' ')     # '%20'
urllib2.unquote('%20') # ' '
```

So why not just unquote the parameter part:

```
f = urllib.urlopen(url, urllib.unquote(urllib.urlencode(params)))
```

Comment: Interesting, for this case that will probably be sufficient, I imagine there are some types params that need to be a protected.

Comment: for python3 I achieved the same for params -> ```unquote(urlencode(params, quote_via=quote_plus))``` with ```from urllib.parse import urlencode, quote_plus, unquote```