# Python requests: having a space in header for posting

Tags: python, c++, apache, header, python-requests

I'm trying to post to a server using the following script:

```
import requests                                                                                                                                                                                                 
data = {                                                                                                      
  'query': 'GetProcess',
  'getFrom': '2018-12-06 10:10:10.000',                                                                     
}                                                                                                                                                                                               
response = requests.post('http://localhost/monitor', data=data)
```

I cannot find where exactly, but the space character in the `getFrom` element is being replaced with a `+`: `'2018-12-06+10:10:10.000'`

This doesn't match the syntax SQL expects on our server, so the query fails.

I read here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12528097) that setting the Content-type might help. I tried `text/html`, `text/plain`, `application/json`, and nothing seems to change.

Interestingly, the following (equivalent?) bash command succeeds:
`curl -d 'query=GetProcess&getFrom=2018-12-06 10:10:10.000' localhost/monitor`

I'm looking for a way to make my server receive `"getFrom" : "2018-12-06 10:10:10.000"` in the header.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26068046/spaces-in-a-url-when-using-requests-and-python (OP of that question acknowledged answer as correct without accepting it)

Comment: curl has debug and trace flags for the command line, those might help you to see what is sent to the server and you can rebuild it in Python.

Comment: @KuboMD OP is already using the `data` dict to pass the arguments

Comment: @KuboMD I believe my question already uses elements of answer provided in this answer from the link you provided: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26070633/5565172. The difference is that in my `payload`, one of my elements has a space, which is the root of my problem.

Comment: Interesting. I can't seem to reproduce this. I booted up a quick flask server and when using your `requests` code to send a POST request I get in the server `ImmutableMultiDict([('query', 'GetProcess'), ('getFrom', '2018-12-06 10:10:10.000')])` Can you provide some more details? I think the problem is on your server side trying to convert `getFrom` to a format that it knows, and not in `requests`

Comment: @DeepSpace 
My mistake, sorry.

Comment: Try json.dumps(data), as in requests.post(URL, json=json.dumps(data))

Comment: @E. Serra: I just tried it, but the response I receive is completely empty. It was a good idea, let me know if you want me to try something else

Comment: @DeepSpace Interesting, I'll try and have a look

Comment: @DeepSpace 
In my C++ module receiving the post, I do `StringMap KeyValHeader; read_post(r, dataVector, KeyValHeader, remaining, totalsize); std::cout << "KeyValHeader[getFrom]: " << KeyValHeader["getFrom"] << std::endl;`

Here's what I get:


`using curl: KeyValHeader[getFrom]: 2018-12-10 06:10:10.000`
`using python requests: KeyValHeader[getFrom]: 2018-12-10+06:10:10.000`

Comment: @FelixLeroux Very weird. I'd either open a new question, or add the c++ tag and add the server code.

Comment: @DeepSpace Good idea, done

Comment: Found the solution, posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to make this work: the problem I was having was due to the use of the `urlencode` function used in `requests`. In the `requests` documentation, it is shown how to go around this default behavior using `PreparedRequests`: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#prepared-requests

Essentially, instead of using the `requests.post()` wrapper, make the function calls explicitly. This way, you will be able to control exactly what is sent. In my case, the solution was to do:

```
import requests
data = {                                                                                                  
    'query': 'GetProcess',                                                                                                                                                                                     
    'getFrom': '2018-12-06 10:10:10.000'
}
s = requests.Session()
req = requests.Request('POST', 'http://'+ipAddress+'/monitor', data=data)
prepped = s.prepare_request(req)
prepped.body = prepped.body.replace("+", " ")
response = s.send(prepped)
```